# In spark structured streaming, is there a way to sleep the read operation during maintenance window for the database

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am developing a spark structured streaming job that reads from a Kafka topic and writes to Jdbc Database.

**The Database is supposed to have a maintenance window and I am trying to figure out a way of handling the case without aborting the job.**

My code:

```
// read data from kafka and transform into required DF.
val transformDF = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.kafkaBootstrapServers)
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("subscribePattern", config.topics)
  .load()
  .transform(toRaw)

//write
val query = transformDF
  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", config.checkpointLocation)
  .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
   batchDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", config.url)
  .option("user", config.username)
  .option("password", config.password)
  .option(JDBCOptions.JDBC_TABLE_NAME, tableName.get)
  .option("stringtype", "unspecified")
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .save()
    })
  }.outputMode(OutputMode.Append()).start()

try {
  query.awaitTermination()
} catch {

  case e: Exception => logger.error("Error", e)
}
```

Right now, if DB is not available the code goes to exception block and is aborted. I want to avoid that, instead, I want the further reading of messages to be halted. I am trying to avoid the manual process of resubmitting the job.

Is this possible?

Spark: 2.4.5

Comment: In that case I´d suggest to try Akka Kafka(Alpakka) that provides backpressure. That means when a stream´s internal buffers is full because the sink is not available it can stop the process of pulling messages from the broker. There was a backpressure control with DStream that you can check too.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 Akka Kafka is not an option for us.

Comment: It's interesting in that it is not addressed in the Spark official docs. Also the fact that DEV OPPs things mean graceful termination. And re-start.

Comment: Have you tried the ForeachWriter interface? You could implement your own re-try mechanism in there.

Comment: @mike what if the DB goes offline there during that processing? need at least idempotent stuff at the target? Unless I am wrong

Comment: did u resolve btw?

Comment: Not yet. On the unavailability of DB, I am looking to put the batch in a new Kafka topic. I will have a separate job that would be responsible for reading from the new topic and putting them on DB. For our use case, data loss is not an option but duplication of message won't be an issue as the separate compaction job would take care of it. Not a solution I am inclined too but I guess would help us in the use case.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not in a reliable way. BTW, No is also an answer.

Logic for checking exceptions are generally via try / catch running on the driver and is as you have coded. That is the accepted paradigm and logical as well one could argue. But this approach is the driver generated error.

As unexpected situations at Executor level are already standardly handled by the Spark Framework itself for Structured Streaming, and if the error is non-recoverable, then the App / Job simply crashes after signalling of error(s) back to the driver unless you code try / catch within the various foreachXXX constructs. That said, it is not clear the micro batch will be recoverable in such an approach afaics, some part of the microbatch is highly likely lost. Hard to test though.

Given that Spark has things standardly catered for that you cannot hook into, why would it be possible to insert a loop / try/catch in the source of the program? Likewise broadcast variables area an issue - although some have techniques around this so they say.  But it is not in the spirit of the framework.

So, good question as I wonder(ed) about this (in the past).